# How to get a custom list from yaml file using ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Using this yaml I'm trying to get a list of the 'Machine' attribute.

```
domainInfo:
    AdminUserName: '--FIX ME--'
    AdminPassword: '--FIX ME--'
topology:
    Name: 'wld-pil-10'
    ConfigBackupEnabled: true
    AdminServerName: 'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0'
    DomainVersion: 12.2.1.4.0
    ProductionModeEnabled: true
    ArchiveConfigurationCount: 20
    Cluster:
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-c01':
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
    Server:
        'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0':
            ListenPort: 11030
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n0'
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10022
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n1'
        'test-bruno-jee-r02a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10025
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n2'
```

I can get a list of the servers by putting the yaml in a variable named "yaml_domain_file" and this code:

- set_fact:
  servers: "{{ yaml_domain_file.topology.Server | list }}"

I get:

ok: [wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0] => {
"msg": [
"wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0",
"test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n1",
"test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n2"
]
}

I'm trying to get the list of machines with this code:

- debug:
  msg: "{{ yaml_domain_file.topology.Server.*.Machine | list }}"

but is not possible. How to get that information?

Thanks to everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try json_query

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ yaml_domain_file.topology.Server|json_query('*.Machine') }}"
```

---

> Q: **"*what If I want to put each of the servers in an array?*"**

A: The simplest option is [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) filter. For example

```yaml
 - set_fact:
     servers: "{{ yaml_domain_file.topology.Server|dict2items }}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the yaml branch of "topology" inside a variable?

Comment: `- set_fact: my_var="{{ yaml_domain_file.topology }}"` prehaps?

Comment: what If I want to put each of the servers in an array?

Comment: There are many options. See `dict2items` for example. The next option would be the modification of `json_query`.

Comment: Something like this? - name: Collect detail of servers
  vars:
    servers_detail: []
  set_fact:
    servers_detail: "{{ yaml_domain_file.topology.Server | json_query([item]) }}"
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"